# How do I use Async pipe to display list

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to use the Async pipe to display my list. I continually get the error invalid pipe argument [object Object] for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

I have used the snapshot changes instead of the value changes since I need both the list and the key. I have mapped the observable to the interface and then subscribe to it in the admin-product component. The list does not show up at all, but when I remove the async on the Html the list shows up.

```
/////////PRODUCT SERVICE.ts///////////

getAll() {
    return this.db.list('/products')
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(changes =>
                changes.map(c => {
                    const data = c.payload.val() as Product;
                    const id = c.payload.key;
                    return { id, ...data };
                })
            )
        );
}


////// Product Interface///////

export interface Product {
    title: string;
    price: number;
    category: string;
    imageUrl: string;
}



////Admin-Products Component//////

import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService} from './../../product.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {Product } from './../../models/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.css']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
products: Product[];
filteredProducts: any[];
subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
  this.subscription = this.productService.getAll()
  .subscribe(products => this.filteredProducts = this.products = products)

}

filter(query: string) {
  this.filteredProducts = (query) ?
  this.products.filter(p => p.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) :
  this.products;
}

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }


//// Admin-Products.component.html /////


<p>
  <a routerLink='/admin/products/new' class='btn btn-primary'>New Product</a>
</p>
<p>
  <input
  #query
  (keyup)='filter(query.value)'
  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
</p>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor='let p of filteredProducts | async '>
      <td>{{p?.title}}</td>
      <td>{{p?.price}}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <a [routerLink]='["/admin/products/", p?.$key]'>edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: filteredProducts is an array, not an observable or a promise. So there's no need for any async pipe here.

Comment: I'm still new to programming and trying to understand. If I do not use the async pipe then I lose the ability to have that constant refresh. I used the async pipe before in this project and it worked; however, when I added the input on the HTML and instituted the filter method then the async pipe broke. I am trying to understand why that happened, and how I can fix this code to be able to use the async pipe so that I can have that real-time update.

Comment: Is `p?.$key` an observable inside an object? I believe this is where the issue is.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea if that is right or not. I know in older versions we could use $key to access the key of the firebase database, but that changed and now we use the snapshotChanges method and then map it. I am not sure what that changes to with the new implementation.

Comment: If you want to use async you must expose the observable itself in your component, and not subscribe to it, since that's what the async pipe does.

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work. To clarify. There are multiple ways to access the data inside an observable. One method is to subscribe directly another way is to use the Async pipe. In my case, I was doing both.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was both subscribing to the observable and using the Async pipe. Here is where I corrected the code to make it work.

```
  ////Old Code//// 


     <tr *ngFor='let p of filteredProducts | async '>
          <td>{{p?.title}}</td>
          <td>{{p?.price}}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <a [routerLink]='["/admin/products/", p?.$key]'>edit</a>
          </td>


    //// New Code //// 

    <tr *ngFor='let p of filteredProducts'>
          <td>{{p?.title}}</td>
          <td>{{p?.price}}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <a [routerLink]='["/admin/products/", p.id]'>edit</a>
```